# jQuery Sparklines 2.0 not working with IE9

Tags: jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-9, sparklines

I'm using jQuery Sparklines (http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline) to draw charts, it's working very well on FF&Chrome
but when testing it on IE9 it's not working, and gives an error in sparkline lib
the error is:

> SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
>   jquery.sparkline.min.js, line 4 character 3378

is it a problem with IE9 support to jQuery? and what i can do to solve this?

Comment: try replacing your non minified version with minified one if you are not using minified version

Comment: i was using the minified version, and i tried the non minified one and i have the same error

Comment: which version are you using of sparkles if it is the latest version 2.0 then it requires jquery version 1.4.3 and above please check your jquery version

Comment: the versions are: sparklines 2.0, jquery 1.7.2, and still getting same error

Comment: i have not used this plugin but was just trying to help by my experience with jquery and all please also check that you are not adding reference to ant of the external 'JS' twice in your page

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery.sparkline 2.1.2 - http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/
Then this got fixed.